# If the speed of a light wave decreases, doesn't the frequency decrease as well?

Tags: waves, dispersion

The dispersion of white light is due to the fact that violet light slows down more when entering a denser medium, compared to red light. However, doesn't the violet light disperse more because it's frequency is reduced more compared to the frequency of the red light?

Comment: The frequency does change but the speed and wavelength do change.

Answer (score 1):

The general stance is as follows: The frequency of light emitted by a source is a property of the source, hence stays the same as wave moves from one medium to another, the wavelength is medium-dependent and changes in accordance with the relation $v = \lambda \nu$, where $v$ is the velocity of light in the medium. Thus, wavelength is higher in vacuum than in a material medium for all colors.

Inside a dispersive medium however, a difference emerges between red and violet because of the fact that the refractive index of the medium is different for different wavelengths, given approximately as $\mu = A + \frac{B}{\lambda^2}$, the so called Cauchy's relation. If we write $\mu = c/v$, we observe that the reason why light disperses in a prism is because the $v$ itself is different for different wavelengths, which explains the assertions in your post.

Comment: Two points:Why would slowing the speed of light cause it to change direction? When I slow my car down it doesn't change direction.

Comment: @Lambda - Do you know/have you read about the [Huygens Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) and particularly, the Huygens construction? I believe those two answers are very standard, and can be easily found using Google. If you are unable to dig them out on your own, then feel free to ping me again, I'll explain that to you. :)