# Is there a way to manipulate/interfere sun light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, solar-cells

[What happens when yellow light is passed through a prism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312609)

[If the speed of a light wave decreases, doesn't the frequency decrease as well?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332206)

is there a way to manipulate/interfere sun light or a way to somehow produce a kind of resonance, to create microwave (in singular?/monochrome?) from sun light without reducing the intensity for the increase of efficiency of voltaic cell?

Comment: This is *much* too broad for this site's format - you should separate it into three or more different questions addressing the different aspects you're including here. Some are duplicates of existing questions (linked here, and at their Linked sidebars on the right) and you should be much more explicit about what it is about the existing answers you find confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> supposed visible light (sun) filtered using colored transparent
>   substance that allowed red and green light to pass through. what is
>   the resulted light's property/characteristic? what is the different
>   between the yellow colored light resulted from a prism?

The difference is the colour (spectra)

> supposed visible light (sun) passed through prism made of colored
>   transparent substance that allowed red and green light to pass
>   through. what is the resulted light's property/characteristic?

Depends on the filters and prism but probably spatially separated red and gree light.

> Our eyes can perceive yellow light both monochromatic light as well as
>   combinations of red and green light. What is the reason? Is there
>   similarity or relation between the two?

Colour is something that is made up in your brain it is not a physical property of the light.

> If the speed of a light wave decreases, doesn't the frequency decrease
>   as well?, by manipulating the speed/length/frequency of light (sun),
>   will the light's color we sense change?

No the frequency doesn't decrease. The wavelength and speed will change.

> by manipulating the frequency of light (sun), is there a way to
>   produce a kind of resonance? or, the reason we can see object around
>   is the result of the so called resonance?

This doesn't make any sense and its not really how we see.

> by manipulating the frequency of light (sun), is there a way to create
>   microwave (in singular?/monochrome?) without reducing the intensity
>   for the increase of efficiency of voltaic cell?

Nope